# ros2 run bash script from Python package

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to be able to run a bash script using `ros2 run <my package> <my shell script>`.  I have added the shell script (`estop_nogui.sh`) to the `setup.py` of the package (it's a Python package) as follows:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'spot_ros2 = spot_driver.spot_ros2:main',
        'spot_commander = spot_driver.spot_commander:main',
        'estop_gui = spot_driver.estop_gui:main',
    ],
},
scripts = [
    'scripts/estop_nogui.sh',
],
```

This results in the file installed at `install/spot_driver/lib/spot_driver/`.  It's an executable file but `ros2 run` can't find it.  What else do I need to do for this?

Thanks!

-Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411104/ros2-run-bash-script-from-python-package/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2023-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I had two problems:

1. I had built in the wrong directory.  Once I built in the correct directory `ros2 run` was able to find the script.
2. Once `ros2 run` did find it I get an "Exec format error" because I was missing `#! /bin/bash` at the top of the script.

With these two fixes, this is working!

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2023-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0